# Replace certain words in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

The method `plant()` takes a `String` and a 2D array of `String[][]` as its inputs. The strings within the array should not be replaced by the inputted word.

```java
public static void plant(String veggie, String[][] garden) {
    String[] veggies =
            {"broccoli", "cactus", "carrot", "corn", "potato", "pumpkin"};
    // YOUR CODE HERE in RED
}
```

The 2D array:

```java
String[][] garden = {
        {"cactus", "carrot", "potato", "fish taco", "broccoli"},
        {"wombat", "corn", "mr bautista", "tomato", "pumpkin"},
        {"potato", "carrot", "toast", "mr bautista", "potato"},
        {"broccoli", "broccoli", "yellowfin tuna", "orc", "cactus"}};
```

Example:

```java
// the word pumpkin is what we are using
// to replace the words we don't want
plant("pumpkin", garden);
```

This should be the output:

```
{{"cactus", "carrot", "potato", "pumpkin", "broccoli"},
 {"pumpkin", "corn", "pumpkin", "pumpkin", "pumpkin"},
 {"potato", "carrot", "pumpkin", "pumpkin", "potato"},
 {"broccoli", "broccoli", "pumpkin", "pumpkin", "cactus"}};
```

**Note:** The method `plant()` does not return anything.

Comment: Hello, you posted your task, but what is your question?  Did you try to implement this assignment?

Comment: Oh im trying to figure out how to exactly write plant()

Comment: exactly as written in assignment: `replace everything, that is not provided in second parameter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```java
public static void plant(String veggie, String[][] garden) {
    String[] veggies =
            {"broccoli", "cactus", "carrot", "corn", "potato", "pumpkin"};
    // YOUR CODE HERE in RED
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(veggies));
    for (int i = 0; i < garden.length; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < garden[i].length; ++j)
            if (!set.contains(garden[i][j]))
                garden[i][j] = veggie;
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(garden));
}
```

The output format, however, is slightly different. I'm sure you can manage, though.